# Avoid casting with a common Interface with additional methods

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, software-design

I have 2 classes, both having a common base class. But on top they have additional Methods that are unique to each class.
They are managed in a collection of objects of the base type.

Now whenever I want to use the additional methods, I have to check for the type and cast.

How can I avoid that?
So far I've come up with

- implementing dummy Methods (and ignoring them)
- casting (I find that not very elegant)
- visitor pattern (but have the functionality in the visitor)

I want to find out if anybody has other ideas.
(Pseudo code)

```
Interface CommonBase
{
    void Common method()
}

class SubClassA : CommonBase
{
    void Extra MethodA()
}

class SubClassB : CommonBase
{
    void Extra MethodB()
}
```

I have a list `List<CommonBase>`.
How do I avoid casting before calling Method A/B? Or somehow executing the functionality of Method A/B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you are trying to accomplish is that you want to refer your sub class instances with the base class/interface type but you want to invoke methods that are specific to the sub classes. This is contradictory because when processing objects that are of different types but having a common base, it is assumed that the processor doesn't care about the sub types, but in your case, the processor does care about the sub type and wants to do sub type specific things. You are right that one way of doing it is to check the type using instanceof operator and cast it and yes it is not very elegant.

Another way and probably the only way I could think of is to have another method with a generic name in the CommonBase such as "delegate" or "process" without defining what it does internally and then provide an implementation in the sub types for this method.

```
interface CommonBase {
   void delegate();
}
class SubTypeA implements CommonBase {
   public void delegate() {
       //invoke actual method with proper name
   }
}
class SubTypeB implements CommonBase {
   public void delegate() {
       //invoke actual method with proper name
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.